# Convert Physical file to blob and show it on the browser

Tags: coldfusion, blob

I want to show confidential files to the browser but the files are outside of the `www` folder so I need to make some processing in coldfusion as the files are somehow protected from public.

So I am converting the physical files, from the server directory, to binary data then `base-64` to show them to the browser. Perhaps Something I am missing even though I am very close to it.

If there is something better than the "blobs" approach let me know.

```
variables.filePath = expandPath('../uploads/myfile.pdf');
local.myFile = fileReadBinary(variables.filePath);
            
local.myFile = toBase64(local.myFile,'utf-8');

writeOutput('<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,#local.myFile#"></object>');
```

https://cfdocs.org/filereadbinary

https://cfdocs.org/tobase64

Comment: I do not understand why you cannot send them back in binary format

Comment: LOL my code actually worked. I had to restart the server :S

Comment: My question still stands. Are you embedding your document in HTML? Why not just binary?

Comment: Yes I embed my document in html but I convert that to base64, to work. Well That could work as well but I didn't dig into it.

Comment: Well, to embed binary in HTML, it has to be encoded in text format. Sending binary as is is not an option.

Comment: @Tarik yes that's what I did. I converted to base64 which can be understood by browsers.  My question was based on coldfusion, and it actually worked with some JavaScript though which converts the file to a blob object.